# Virtual environment not making a difference after activating

Tags: python, python-venv

I only have 1 library in my local PC, which is numpy. I created a virtual environment in a folder, activated it, and pip installed django in it. django is in my venv's site-packages folder, but if i run pip freeze with my venv active anywhere in my PC it outpunts numpy.
The only way i can run any command that requires the packages installed in the venv is runing it from that folder. 
I have seen many similar questions but they are old or dont answer why this happens.
For example i type in the command line:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop>python -m pip freeze
numpy==1.9.6
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts>python -m pip freeze
Django==2.2.7
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0

C:\Users\eloim\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts>activate

(Venv0) C:\Users\eloim\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts>
(Venv0) C:\Users\eloim\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts>python -m pip freeze
Django==2.2.7
pytz==2019.3
sqlparse==0.3.0

(Venv0) C:\Users\eloim\Desktop>python -m pip freeze
numpy==1.9.6
```

As far as i have read on the docs, after activating the venv i should only be able to find the django packages. Where am i wrong? which concept do i not understand?

Im asking this question because i have to run some commands from django in a specific folder, but anywhere out of the scripts folder wont find the package.

Thanks in advance

--EDIT--
This is what i get when i use where python:

```
C:\Users\myname>where python
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

(Venv0) C:\Users\myname\Desktop>where python
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

(Venv0) C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts>where python
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
```

After seeing this im quite lost. After activating the VE, nothing changes, so why should it be useful?

Also this is what pip freeze alone returns:

```
C:\Users\myname>pip freeze
numpy==1.9.6

(Venv0) C:\Users\myname\Desktop>pip freeze
numpy==1.9.6

(Venv0) C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts>pip freeze
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\myname\venv0\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts\pip.exe" freeze'

C:\Users\eloim\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts>pip freeze
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\eloim\venv0\scripts\python.exe"  "C:\Users\eloim\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts\pip.exe" freeze'
```

So again, it seems that activating a VE actually changes nothing in my python, but this error clearly means something. 
Thanks for the help you have already given.

Comment: Does `pip freeze` (with the env active) show the same thing? What do `where python` and `where pip` show with and without the environment active?

Comment: Diagnose this with `where python`, from both working directories, before and after activation.

Comment: @b_c As shown in the code i posted, i use the freeze comand without activating, and then with the venv active ( (Venv0) at the begining). Same result. I will try the "where" command and see where that takes me.

Comment: Keep in mind, `python -m pip freeze` is _not_ the same as `pip freeze`

Comment: sorry for insisting but I want to fully understand it. If adding "python" at the begining means that it picks the python file from PATH, why do i get 2 different outputs? if it is going to PATH and picking that python, it should always output the same, right? @b_c

Comment: That's what it _should_ do yes, but if (for instance) you have 2 python versions on your PATH, such as 2.7 and 3.7, it would only pick one of them (I'm not sure if it picks the first listed, or the "most recent" listed). I'm wondering if maybe you're seeing something like that with the virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

From your description , there is 2 observation.

> 1. 'C:\Users\myname\Desktop' is your main Python Installation directory
> 2. You have installed the numpy on 'C:\Users\myname\Desktop' and not in 'C:\Users\eloim\Desktop\Venv0\Scripts'

instead of using 'python -m pip freeze' , just use 'pip freeze'. You will see the difference.

```
To install package in your virtualenv

1. Activate virtual env and install using 'pip install <package>'
```

remember : This is not an issue.

```
In your case , 
1. the keyword 'python' is creating a confusion for you. 
2. When you use python , it is considering the 'python.exe' path , rather than the directory you are in.
```

Comment: in your point number 2, how do you explain the fact that i have python at the begining of every command line i type but get diferent results?

Comment: When you call `python -m pip freeze`, you're invoking the `pip` module from whichever `python` gets invoked from the call, which could be one you don't expect if you're running into PATH issues. If you run `pip freeze` (like I suggested in my OP comment), you're calling the `pip` executable _directly_ which might be unaffected by the previously mentioned potential PATH issues. You can further diagnose this with the `where` calls.